# Google coral SOM temperatures

Tags: google-coral

My coral soms are running a bit hotter than I would like.  They have a passive heat sink, but they are outside in a weatherproof enclosure.  On the hottest days, some do get past the 95C thermal tripping point.  I have lowered my cpu frequency to 1GHz (that helped a lot) and I have turned off two cores (that did not help much).  I am constantly using two cores at ~60% load and I am not using the tpu.  Still, the coral SOM runs about 20C hotter than a raspberry pi CM4 which I feel is a pretty comparable processor.  What else can I do to get my temps down?  I heard the latest IMX8MQ silicon revision is supposed to run a lot cooler.  Is there any plan to use the newer silicon revision on newly manufactured devices?  Mine are about a year old and are silicon revision B0.  I'm running imx linux kernel version 5-15-lf if that matters.